# .NET custom DbContextFactory registration to DI

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, factory

i created my own dbcontextfactory and now i don't know how to correctly register it in di. Can you somebody help me please? IApplicationDbContext is just interfaces with db sets.
I have register ma DbContext as pooled db context factory

```
builder.Services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<MyContext>(options =>
{
    ....
});
```

Interface of my db factory

```
interface IApplicationDbContextFactory
{
    IApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext();
}
```

Implementation db factory

```
public class MyContextFactory<TContext> : IApplicationDbContextFactory where TContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<TContext> _dbContextFactory;

    public MyContextFactory(IDbContextFactory<TContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public IApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    }
}
```

How can i correctly register my factory to di?
Thank you

Comment: `builder.Services.Addsingleton<IApplicationDbContextFactory, MyContextFactory<MyContext>>()`? Any particular reason why you need to do this?

Comment: AddSingleton cannot be use like this. When i change it to AddScoped its still not working. I get this error: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[MyContext]' while attempting to activate 'MyContextFactory`1[MyContext]. I want use it like this because i want use clean architecture. So i need comunicate over interface and i want use dbcontextfactroy

Comment: _"AddSingleton cannot be use like this"_ - please elaborate.

Comment: @GuruStron sorry i write it bad. I can use AddSingleton bud i get same error. Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory1[MyContext]' while attempting to activate 'MyContextFactory1[MyContext]

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Also TBH not sure how clean architecture and your custom interface are connected. You should be fine with just using context as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifetime for the factory registered by `AddPooledDbContextFactory` is `Singleton`. Just register it with `builder.Services.AddSingleton<IApplicationDbContextFactory, MyContextFactory<MyContext>>();` (though `Scoped` and `Transient` should also work just as fine):

```cs
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddPooledDbContextFactory<SomeContext>(builder => builder.UseSqlite($"Filename={nameof(SomeContext)}.db"));
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IApplicationDbContextFactory, MyContextFactory<SomeContext>>();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var dbContextFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<SomeContext>>();

using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var applicationDbContextFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IApplicationDbContextFactory>();
    var applicationDbContext = applicationDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
}

public class SomeContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public SomeContext(DbContextOptions<SomeContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<MyEntity> Entities { get; set; }
}

interface IApplicationDbContextFactory
{
    IApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext();
}

public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
}

public class MyContextFactory<TContext> : IApplicationDbContextFactory where TContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<TContext> _dbContextFactory;

    public MyContextFactory(IDbContextFactory<TContext> dbContextFactory)
    {
        _dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public IApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return _dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext();
    }
}
```